# Can't add an iOS certificate to CodenameOne

Tags: codenameone

Being on Windows, I have generated an iOS certificate for my app following these steps:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mpzSXAW0qUI

it generates a file called ios-development.cer

When I try to browse and find this file to add it to the "certificate" in the debug section in the relevant Netbeans window (see pic below), the file is not displayed in the file finder (because the wizzard expects a file with a different extension I guess).

Moreover, I never had to add a password in the certificate generation process, so I don't get which password is asked from me at the password field?

[image]

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal way is to use the wizard http://www.codenameone.com/blog/ios-certificate-wizard.html

The certificate needs to be converted to a P12 file using a Mac. This is a bit of a rough process described here: http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---create-an-ios-provisioning-profile.html

and here: http://codenameone.com/signing.html

Then the pitfalls here: http://www.codenameone.com/blog/ios-code-signing-fail-checklist.html

Encryption requires two keys: public and private and the cer file only contains one of them (the other is stored on your Mac) so you need to import the cer into your Mac and then export a P12 file that contains both keys (at which point you provide the password).